# Group by one column and take count of multiple categories in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to group by one column and then take the count of each category within a second column

```
name    location    sku
svc1    ny          hey1
svc2    ny          hey1
svc3    ny          hey1
svc4    ny          hey1
lo1     ny          ok1
lo2     ny          ok1
fab1    ny          hi
fab2    ny          hi
fab3    ny          hi
hello   ca          no
hello   ca          no
```

desired

```
location    sku     count
ny          hey1    4
ny          ok1     2
ny          hi      3
ca          no      2
```

doing

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['sku'] = df.groupby('location')['sku'].nth(0)
df2['count'] = df.groupby('sku').count()
```

However, I am getting NAN for count, and I am not getting all of the data listed under sku.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to group by two columns:

```
df.groupby(['location','sku']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Or groupby one column and `value_counts` the other:

```
# this should be slightly faster
(df.groupby('location')['sku'].value_counts()
      .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Output:

```
  location   sku  count
0       ca    no      2
1       ny  hey1      4
2       ny    hi      3
3       ny   ok1      2
```